# Waiting for a Python's spawn when executing a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, asynchronous, spawn

I was making a Discord bot with 'discord.js' but I need to work with Python's Pandas module.

I need to execute a Python function inside a Javascript one that updates a '.csv' file and then the Javascript command continues and send that updated '.csv' file.

For this, I need that the Javascript's command waits for the Python's spawn to finish executing and then proceed with the rest of the command, but I can't get it to work.

To explain my problem further, I created a simple example:

Inside the Javascript's code I have this written

```
async function main() {
    console.log("J: Hey...")
    console.log("J: I can't count to 5...")
    console.log("J: Can you help me, Mr. Python?")

        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        py = spawn('python', [`main.py`]),
        data = [],
        dataString = '';    //  python's console

        py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
            dataString += data.toString(); 
        }); 

        py.stdout.on('end', function(){             
            console.log(dataString)
        });

        py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        py.stdin.end();

    console.log("J: Thank you, mister!")

}

main()
```

And inside the Python's code I have this:

```
def main():
    print("P: Of course!")
    print("P: It's like this:")
    for i in range(5): print(f"P: {i + 1}")
    print("P: Hope that it helps!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is what I need after the code is executed:

```
J: Hey...
J: I can't count to 5...
J: Can you help me, Mr. Python?
P: Of course!
P: It's like this:
P: 1
P: 2
P: 3
P: 4
P: 5
P: Hope that it helps!
J: Thank you, mister!
```

But this is what I receive:

```
J: Hey...
J: I can't count to 5...
J: Can you help me, Mr. Python?
J: Thank you, mister!
P: Of course!
P: It's like this:
P: 1
P: 2
P: 3
P: 4
P: 5
P: Hope that it helps!
```

I'm not expert in asynchronous programming, so I don't know much about how to get to the correct solution.

I tried to explore new forms to execute Python's code inside Javascript, but I couldn't get so far.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Node’s `child_process.spawn` method returns a `ChildProcess` object. You can set handlers for the child process’s events, to get a signal when the process closes, and continue with your local code in that. You would probably want to listen for other events, like error, exit, etc. too, just in case. There are some pretty good examples in the Node documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options

Comment: Thank you very much! But I want to ask, can you give me an example of a handler that will help me? I don't know anything about handlers

Comment: Wait, I think that I get what you meant.
Did you meant that I should add the next line of code I want to execute after the spawn finishes? Like, something like this: (https://pastebin.com/UT4JDydr)?

If so,  there's another way or the only way is to continue executing my Javascript code inside a spawn's event?

Comment: Well, I’m not sure I’d say the code is running "in the spawn’s event.” It’s running in response to the spawned process’s end event, which is to say when the process has ended. I’m not a Node expert, but it looks like that’s the way they it’s done, as opposed to some kind of Wait-For-Process method.